# flutter onboarding - how to keep "proportions"?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created onboarding in my flutter app:
This is my data model:

```
class Data {
 final String image;
 final String title;
 final String desc;

 Data(this.image, this.title, this.desc); }

 final List<Data> items = [
  Data('assets/1.png', '1', '1'),
  Data('assets/2.png', '2', '2'),
  Data('assets/3.png', '3', '3')
];
```

This is my code:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    children: [
      PageView.builder(
        controller: _pageController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var item = items[index];
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(item.image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            //bloc1  
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [Text(item.title), Text(item.desc)],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      //bloc 2
      SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
            child: Text('****dots indicators****'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Next'),
          )
        ],
      ))
    ],
  ),
);
```

This onBoading consists of three parts:

1. background image
2. text block - block1
3. "lower action block" - block2.

I need to have a small fixed distance between blocks 1 and 2 - 10pх.
but also I can't place block1 and block2 together. I need block1 to be "inside" PageView, block2 on the main page.

right now I'm using the bottom padding. but this is not a reliable solution - this size may change on different screens - "overlapping" will occur.

how can I fix this problem? Any advice - I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position your "page indicator dots" at a fixed relative spot, for example, 10% from the bottom of the screen, an easy solution is to use the `Align` widget.

However in your case, you must also change the `Column` in your to `MainAxisSize.min`, so that its height will be as small as possible, leaving you enough freedom to decide where to position the `Column` vertically. For example:

```
      SafeArea(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0, 0.95), // relative position
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // make Column shorter
            children: [
              Text('****dots indicators****'),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Next'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

For the `alignment` property of the `Align` widget, the values are `(x, y)` ranging from `-1 to +1`, with `0` being the center. For example, you can use alignment: `Alignment(0, -0.5)` to make it center horizontally, and 50% towards the top on the vertical axis.